# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file'

Tags: .net, multithreading, f#, locking

I am trying to synchronize logging to a file in an F Sharp project. Using the lock computational expression I tried to approximate a resource lock, however it seems to not be working.

```
module regiondeployer.logger

open System
open System.IO
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core
open regiondeployer.personalprojectroot

type private logginglock =
    static member public lock = new Object()

[<Literal>]
let private logfile = personalprojectroot + "log.txt" 

let public initialize() : unit = 
    use init = File.Create(logfile)
    ()

let public logtoconsoleandfile (message:string) : unit =
    lock logginglock.lock (fun _ -> 
        Console.WriteLine message
        use logfilestream = File.AppendText(logfile)
        logfilestream.WriteLine(message)
    )
```

> System.IO.IOException   HResult=0x80070020   Message=The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'log.txt'
>   because it is being used by another process.   Source=mscorlib

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this on Windows, or on Linux? The two OSes use a different model for file locking, so something that works well on Linux won't necessarily work on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `logginglock.lock` is a property with a getter and so a new object is returned each time you access it. As a result, the threads will end up locking different objects and actually access the file concurrently.

If you insist on having the lock object as a field of a static object, then you can define a static field using `static let` and then just return the object:

```
type private logginglock() =
    static let _lock = new obj()
    static member public lock = _lock
```

That said, it would work equally well if you just had the lock object as a global value in a module (as long as it is private to the module). This will likely compile to something very similar as the code above - though there are all sorts of subtleties around locking objects and singletons that I never quite understood...

```
let private loggingLock = obj()
```

Comment: I had no idea static variables were possible!

Comment: @SamuelJ Global `let` bindings in a module are compiled as static fields of some hidden class - the F# language does not think of them as "static" because they are just let bindings, but since they're not specific to any class instance, they are static in .NET terms :-)